# We all know how to SKI, but can you BCKW?

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming, combinatory-logic, lambda-calculus

### Background

[Lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) is a model of computation using *lambda terms*.

- A variable \$x\$ is a lambda term.
- If \$E\$ is a lambda term, the lambda abstraction \$\lambda x. E\$ is a lambda term.
- If \$E_1, E_2\$ are lambda terms, the lambda application \$E_1 E_2\$ is a lambda term.

The rule of computation is called \$\beta\$-reduction: \$(\lambda x. E_1) E_2\$ is reduced to \$E_1\$ in which every occurrence of \$x\$ is replaced with \$E_2\$. For example, \$(\lambda x. x x)(\lambda y. y)\$ is reduced to \$(\lambda y. y)(\lambda y. y)\$, then to \$\lambda y. y\$.

[Combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) operates on a similar premise, but instead of variables and lambda abstraction, it uses a fixed set of combinators. Each combinator has a fixed arity, and it is \$\beta\$-reduced only when it gets enough number of arguments applied to it.

For example, \$S\$ and \$K\$ have following reduction rules:

$$
\begin{align}
S x y z &\mapsto x z (y z) \\
K x y &\mapsto x
\end{align}
$$

\$S\$ has an arity of 3, so \$SKK\$ is not reducible. But if you apply one more argument to it, it reduces to \$SKKx \mapsto Kx(Kx) \mapsto x\$, which shows that \$SKK\$ is extensionally equal to the identity function \$\lambda x. x\$ in lambda calculus.

[SKI combinator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) is a well-known *complete* combinatory logic system, i.e. a system where any arbitrary lambda calculus term can be represented. [This section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) shows how to transform any given lambda term into a SKI expression.

[BCKW system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system) is a lesser known complete system, discovered by Haskell Curry in 1930. It uses four combinators defined as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
B x y z &\mapsto x (y z) \\
C x y z &\mapsto x z y \\
K x y &\mapsto x \\
W x y &\mapsto x y y
\end{align}
$$

In Haskell terms, \$B\$ equals `(.)`, \$C\$ equals `flip`, and \$K\$ equals `const`. Haskell doesn't have a built-in for \$W\$, but it is equal to `(<*>id)`.

### Challenge

Given a lambda term, convert it to an equivalent term in BCKW system.

The I/O format is flexible. The lambda term and BCKW term can be represented as a string notation ([fully parenthesized](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205809/78410) or using [prefix notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112115/78410)) or a (pre-parsed) nested structure. It is also allowed to use four distinct values (numbers, chars, strings) in place of BCKW combinators. The lambda term can also use [de Bruijn indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) or other directly equivalent representations.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples

There are infinitely many different correct outputs for every input, so these are merely examples of possible conversions.

```
\x. x
=>  W K  or  B C C
\x. x x
=>  W (W K)
\x y z. x (y z)
=>  B
\x y z. z x y
=>  B C (C (W K))
\f g x y. f (g x) (g y)
=>  B W (B (B C) (B (B (B B)) B))
\x y z. y (y y) y
=>  K (W (W (W (B (B (B (B K))) B))))
\f x. f (f (f x))
=>  W (W (C (B B (B B B)) B))
```

Comment: Might also note that although it's not quite as built in a Haskell equivalent of \$W\$ is `(<*>id)`

Comment: Haskell has a builtin for \$W\$. It's `join` specialized for the Reader monad.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 133 bytes

```hs
data T=T:@T|L T|V Int|B|C|K|W
l(x:@y)=W:@(B:@(C:@l x):@l y)
l(V 0)=W:@K
l(V n)=K:@V(n-1)
l x=K:@x
f(L x)=l$f x
f(x:@y)=f x:@f y
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZA7b4MwFIV3fsUZOthDokI3S5aspEsFU4NIVyuYBNVxKqAtSP7tpZdHGpFamPv47jm2fNL1u7G273PdaKQyFSr1CVKf4cU1fuO3Pvb7wLJWqI7LvVBsQ3srlEXLh3/HiWZ4HGE85o7LWKiMuVVIEO1QtUHBEpJI@1BgKCZDyoUq0AWUyLbPTVV@le6I0tWNdgeD3enyjTT4D16Nzgmcdekgqd2YSh8asE9nS2dqrHHWH2D1oF@joF2RglMcOe8TjNcOpgihcC2nL0M0NCmGV0jrxm@qiE8xXPBp5Gn2iP5Glo3RdOkaLo@dJQv7u6G7O/4cCquPdb9629Fb5dpenHmeH/AX)

Accepts De Bruijn–indexed lambda terms with \$λ\$ written as `L`, application written as `:@`, and variables written `V 0`, `V 1`, … from innermost to outermost.

This uses the standard unoptimized \$SKI\$ abstraction elimination algorithm, with \$Sxy\$ and \$I\$ replaced by \$W(B(Cx)y)\$ and \$WK\$.  As such, it’s very inefficient in terms of output size.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 451 bytes

```python
I='W','K'
F=lambda v,e:v==e[0]or F(v,e[1])if[]==e*0else e!=v if''==e*0else F(v,e[0])and F(v,e[1])
f=lambda x,u:0*x==()and u==x[1]
T=lambda e,v='$':e if''==e*0else(T(e[1][0],v)if f(*e[::-1])and F(e[0],e[1][0])else(('K',T(e[1],v))if F(*e)else(I if e[0]==e[1]else T([e[0],T(*e[::-1])],v))))if[]==e*0else((('W',e[0][0])if f(e,v)else(('C',e[0][0]),e[1]),v)if f(e[0],v)else(((('B',e[0]),e[1][0]),v)if f(e[1],v)else((I,v)if v==e[0]else T(e[0],v),T(e[1],v))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFBa4QwEIXv/ooUCpORFJTehFy2IEivQg8hB7sbqaCurKvYX28niWl2L0PMvO/Nmzj93n@u4/u@VxK@QMAnJKXsm@H70rBVmGKV0qhMX2@s5PStco1dqzTdppnpZ8PMi1xZ1wLEK6/MNDbjJWJJG3w3sRRZuknJnWKRciNBUoe@EauEVyjMsy@vuTUiY7FSCNby1KiieMvDIDtTHBJ0BKd9hMeIsVBJkO9V5M4sYjfMtUtec@VM6mjtQHxempMxPZaV2lEuC4UOMz9iy68e8hqf/bDgcPJC/A8dhXkUVv72@BNHzsPqYTnEfV7OZyaZghEE1dbVjSp3Z5poG3RGqhsgaq2T6daNd3pbCyMmU7/MzmNw9Bi5ICF2AHwgLULT/wA)

Previous byte counts: 628, 617, 559, 552, 536, 506, 495, 480, 472, 461, 456

I was working on a term-rewriting procedure for this in my free time anyways, why not golf it? Input/Output format is strings for variables, <s>tuples</s> lists of length two for lambda abstractions, and <s>lists</s> tuples of length two for applications.

(Reduced char count by switching input/output method)

(Reduced to 559 bytes thanks to @ovs)

Comment: You can shorten all these type checks a bit: `x*0==()` works for `type(x)==tuple`, similar with `""` and `[]` for strings and lists

Comment: Thanks for that tip, ovs.